# Logs not getting created for jars placed inside shared library in WAS

Tags: logging, log4j, shared, ear

I have 3 EARs sharing a Shared Library at EAR level in WAS.
Each EAR contains a single WAR.
I have placed log4j-1.2.15.jar inside each war's WEB-INF/lib and also inside Shared Library.

Now the logs of individual wars are getting created but the logs for code inside the jars placed at Shared Library at EAR level, are not getting created.

I have placed log4j.xml inside each war and at shared library as Well.

If any one can suggest me what could be the root cause for this and how can I achieve the logging for jars placed inside Shared library.

I have also tried placing log4j-1.2.15.jar at EAR level only in that case the war that starts last, initialize the log4j and all logs starts getting created inside that application only. However in this case logs for Shared library also get created.

Thanks

Comment: what have you tryed so far?
show us code... as it stand the question is way to broad/unanswerable